# Running document load on jQuery Mobile with a Prefetched Page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

When I load an initial page the `$(document).ready()` function works just fine.

However - when I prefetch a link to a page that I want to load for UI performance reasons, that page does not run it's document ready method.

Has anyone else run into this?  Any suggestions?

My next thought is to just put the two pages into one, but I would prefer keeping them separate.

Comment: how are you prefetching?

Comment: jQuery Mobile has a method to prefetch that I'm calling. $.mobile.loadPage(url, { showLoadMsg: false });

Comment: Does the $(window).load() event fire?

Comment: Nope. If I was to guess, I would say that jQuery mobile is performing a ajax call to retrieve the page and enter it into the DOM, so I haven't been able to get $(window).load() to fire either.

Comment: what if you do a `$.mobile.loadPage(url, { reloadPage: true });`?

Comment: No luck.  Thanks for the input though Steve.

Comment: jQuery mobile does only parses what is in the body of the fetched page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `$(document).ready()` function for jquery mobile pages because of the prefetching.

The jQuery Doc now highlights this FAQ in the [documentation on events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html).

You should set your event handler via the `pageinit` event.

Example from the doc:

```
$( '#aboutPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
  alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

Also be careful -- because of the AJAX loads the scripts you are using should be on the first page loaded, and actions for other pages should be handled by event handlers.